Assigning property to a particular instance created dynamically in qml
I want to instantiate an image in 'sample.qml' multiple times dynamically depending on the count. I am able to create multiple qml instances in run time as below,
Item {
    id: container
    width: 500; height: 100
    z: 100
    Component.onCompleted: {
         var component = Qt.createComponent("sample.qml");
         for (var i=0; i< model.count; i++) {
             var object = component.createObject(container);
             object.x = (object.width + 250) * i;
         }
     }       
}

Creating is not the issue.
But I want to assign x property to a particular instance in run time. How to achieve this and also how to destroy a particular instance. Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks.
I'm not able to get a particular instance of the component.
Also while using destroy, it is destroying only the last instance created.

It might be easier to use a Repeater to create your items. Read this document to get an idea how to do that: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-repeater.html

As mentioned in the comments, a Repeater is a much better approach. And it gives you the ability to reference a particular instance after they are created.
Item {
    id: container
    width: 500; height: 100
    z: 100

    Repeater {
        id: repeater

        // A model can be as simple as an integer
        model: some_number

        // The delegate is the object that you want repeated
        delegate: SomeObject {
            required property int index

            x: (width + 250) * index
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        // Update the 5th item
        repeater.itemAt(4).color = "blue";
    } 
}

